# ¿como colocar las comillas correctamente?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente código el cual me da el error mostrado, me parece que estoy colocando mal alguna comillas.

```
Declare `@Cuenta Varchar(25),@Fecha Varchar(10),@Moneda Varchar(3),@User Varchar(20)`
Declare `@NomTabla Varchar(60)`  


    SET @User = 'Usuario'
    SET @Cuenta ='190106010105'
    SET @Fecha ='20170812'
    SET @Moneda = 'SOL'
    SET @NomTabla = '##RptMayorDetalle' + @User

    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante WHERE FOLIO LIKE'+ @Fecha+' + ''%''')
```

Me aparece el error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1

Se especificó una expresión no booleana en un contexto donde se esperaba una condición, cerca de `LIKE20170812`.

[image: Se Especificó una expresión no booleana]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `'''` (3 apostrofes) o con `CHAR(39)`

Quedaría así tu consulta

opc1:

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante WHERE FOLIO LIKE '''+ @Fecha + '%''')
```

opc 2:

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM Contabilidad..Comprobante WHERE FOLIO LIKE ' + CHAR(39) + @Fecha + '%' + CHAR(39))
```

Espero te ayude, saludos

Comment: Gracias!!! si me ayudaste, funciono!!!